# I'm trying to write a simple Lua script, and the time function is giving me a "loading module" error

Tags: linux, sockets, ubuntu, lua

I'm trying to learn Lua, and the tutorial I'm following has the following code as a step:

```
 print("Welcome to")
 print("THE GAME")
```

I, having some prior experience programming, decided to take it a step further:

```
 require "socket"

 function sleep(sec)
     socket.select(nil, nil, sec)
 end

 print("Welcome to.....")
 sleep(1.25)
 print("...")
 sleep(1.25)
 print("...")
 sleep(1.25)
 print("...")
 sleep(1.25)
 print("...")
 sleep(1.25)
 print("THE GAME")
```

And for some reason, this small addition immediately gave me an error:

```
  dave@dave-[my laptop]:~/Code/Lua/Test$ lua main.lua
  lua: error loading module 'socket.core' from file '/home/dave/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/socket/core.so':
     /home/dave/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/socket/core.so: undefined symbol: lua_pcall
  stack traceback:
     [C]: in ?
     [C]: in function 'require'
     /home/dave/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/socket.lua:12: in main chunk
     [C]: in function 'require'
     main.lua:1: in main chunk
     [C]: in ?
```

I'm not sure how I broke something this simple. Did I install Lua wrong? I'm running Lua 5.2.3 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Lua is a proper name, not an acronym. It should not be in ALL CAPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `lib/lua/5.1/socket/core.so`
>
> I'm running Lua 5.2.3

Well, there's your problem. Lua is not binary compatible with previous "minor" versions. So you cannot load a .so that was built for Lua 5.1 when you're executing in Lua 5.2.

Assuming the socket library has a 5.2 version, you need to upgrade to it. If you can't do that, then you need to downgrade to Lua 5.1.

Comment: So I either need to upgrade my socket library to 5.2, or downgrade my Lua to 5.1? Where should I go to download the upgraded sockets?